# Is there any full-text search API for cassandra?

Tags: java, full-text-search, cassandra

I installed cassandra (on ubuntu) and I think it's convenient and good. But I didn't build a complete app and further on I expect that I must deliver something like full-text searches and even something like search suggests (with AJAX). I know there are API:s that can do functions like "search suggest" (e.g. JQuery plus some http access to your data can make search suggest with AJAX) so now I wonder if we must build ourselves a search API for cassandra or if there already are some available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there really isn't a good way to do that with vanilla Cassandra, so you're going to have use an additional search tool like [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/).  DataStax has a product (DataStax Enterprise Edition) that tightly integrates Cassandra with Solr (for searching).  Here's a link to the [DSE download](http://www.datastax.com/docs/datastax_enterprise2.0/search/dse_search_start) page.  You can try it out in your DEV environment for free.  They also have a [tutorial on how to get a simple column family indexed in Solr](http://www.datastax.com/docs/datastax_enterprise2.0/search/dse_search_start).

Otherwise, you can integrate Cassandra with Solr on your own, too.  But the nice thing about DSE, is that they take care of the Cassandra/Solr integration.  Also, DSE is currently on Cassandra 1.1.x (I forget the exact version) so if you need to use 1.2.x, you'll have to integrate with Solr on your own anyway.